# ¿Cómo puedo usar el texto que pone el usuario luego de usar el comando en discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

**Esto es lo que quiero lograr hacer.**

En este caso estoy creando un bot, y quiero que cuando el usuario ponga el comando `!text` y luego escriba su usuario `!text id` guardar el texto en una variable, hacer un link y luego enviar el link por el bot.

Ejemplo:

> Usuario: !text miid
> Bot: Aquí tienes el link -> https/miid/.com

```
@client.command()
async def text(ctx, text : str):
   link1 = "http:/"
   link2 = "/.com"
   link = link1 + text + link2
   await ctx.send("Aquí esta tu link", link)
```

El error que obtengo es:

> I File "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Necesito de su ayuda muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de tu bot a la pregunta por favor? Es que quiero saber algo antes de escribir mi respuesta.

Comment: Cual es el error que te sucede?

Comment: En la parte de text

Comment: Pero que error te da exactamente? Por ejemplo "link is not defined"?

Comment: I
  File "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Gracias! Creo que ya vi tu error. Tu error es un tema de logica. Como dice el error, ctx.send solo acepta 1 o 2 argumentos posicionales. Estas pasando el mensaje "aqui esta tu link" y como segundo argumento estás pasando otra cosa. Esos dos argumentos NO se unen en un solo texto. Para arreglarlo, cambia la "," por un "+" para concatenar el mensaje con el link.

Comment: O sea, que "aqui esta tu link" se le agregue el link al final

Comment: Muchas gracias ya salio correcto, eres un grande

Comment: Para la proxima vez que hagas una pregunta, te recomiendo que agregues en esta un ejemplo minimo y verificable de tu código y el error que te sucede si es que hay un error. No somos adivinos y no podemos saber magicamente que estás teniendo un error.

Comment: Me alegro, gracias c:

Comment: Como puedo apoyarte ?

Comment: Gracias por querer apoyarme. Pero como lo resolvimos a través de los comentarios, no hay manera de que me apoyes. Algo que puedes hacer si haces una pregunta y alguien te da una respuesta que NO sea en comentarios, es aceptar su respuesta c:

Comment: Hechale una leida a este link para entender mejor a que me refiero https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Pero gracias igual! c:

Comment: Estube hablando en el chat de SO, y a alguien se le ocurrió la idea de poner lo que te dije en comentarios como respuesta y que así puedas aceptarla c: Sería una buena forma de apoyarme nwn Ya copio el comentario que hice en una respuesta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error es un tema de logica. Como dice el error, ctx.send solo acepta 1 o 2 argumentos posicionales. Estas pasando el mensaje "aqui esta tu link" y como segundo argumento estás pasando otra cosa. Esos dos argumentos NO se unen en un solo texto. Para arreglarlo, cambia la "," por un "+" para concatenar el mensaje con el link.

Quedaría así:

```
await ctx.send("Aquí esta tu link"+link)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda